# how to recognized jwt token from different tenant nestjs muti-tenant jwt

Tags: jwt, multi-tenant, nestjs

I implement multi-tenant by multiple databases and use jwt token as authorization, my concern is that when user 1 of tenant 2 login and get the jwt token, when he uses to token to access another tenant, does he recognized as user 1 of tenant 2? If so, how can we fix it?

My Strategy

`jwt.strategy.ts`

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,

    private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      passReqToCallback: true,
      secretOrKey: configService.get('JWT_SECRET_KEY'),
    });
  }

  async validate(request: Request, jwtPayload: JwtPayload) {
    const contextId = ContextIdFactory.getByRequest(request);

    const authService: AuthService = await this.moduleRef.resolve(
      AuthService,
      contextId,
    );

    let { iat, exp } = jwtPayload;
    const timeDiff = exp - iat;

    if (timeDiff <= 0) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return jwtPayload;
  }
}
```

My Auth Service

`auth.service.ts`

```js
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
    private readonly userService: UsersService,
    private readonly auctionHouseService: AuctionHouseService,
  ) {}

  async createToken(user: User) {
    let plainUser: any = Object.assign({}, user);
    plainUser.auctionHouseId = (
      await this.auctionHouseService.getCurrentAuctionHouse()
    ).id;
    return {
      expiresIn: this.configService.get('JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME'),
      accessToken: this.jwtService.sign(plainUser),
    };
  }

}
```

My Login controller

`auth.controller.ts`

```js
@Controller('api/auth')
@ApiUseTags('authentication')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly userService: UsersService,
  ) {}

  @Post('login')
  @ApiResponse({ status: 201, description: 'Successful Login' })
  @ApiResponse({ status: 400, description: 'Bad Request' })
  @ApiResponse({ status: 401, description: 'Unauthorized' })
  async login(@Body() payload: LoginPayload, @Req() req): Promise<any> {
    let user = await this.authService.validateUser(payload);

    return omitPassword(await this.authService.createToken(user));
  }
```

Comment: do you want to authorize the user based on the signature?

Comment: Set [`audience`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1.3) for the signed token to the tenant and check that when validating the user

Comment: @GuerricP Yes, because it is a multi-tenant program that if user id 1 from tenant A use his token to access tenant B, he will recognized as user id 1 right?

Comment: @Oluwafemi Sule , looks like a good solution ?```
const contextId = ContextIdFactory.getByRequest(request);




const tenancy: TenancyIns = await this.moduleRef.resolve(
      INJECTION_SCOPE,
      contextId,
      { strict: false },
);




if (parseInt(tenant.aud) != tenancy.tenant.id) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
}```

Answer (score 2):

In general, the correct way to identify the domain within which a JWT is valid is the `aud` (or audience) field. Per [RFC7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3):

> The "aud" (audience) claim identifies the recipients that the JWT is
> intended for.  Each principal intended to process the JWT MUST
> identify itself with a value in the audience claim.  If the principal
> processing the claim does not identify itself with a value in the
> "aud" claim when this claim is present, then the JWT MUST be
> rejected.  In the general case, the "aud" value is an array of case-
> sensitive strings, each containing a StringOrURI value.  In the
> special case when the JWT has one audience, the "aud" value MAY be a
> single case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI value.  The
> interpretation of audience values is generally application specific.
> Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

In your context, you'd want to select unique audiences for each of your tenants (let's say it's `tenant1` and `tenant2`) and when generating your JWT you'd do something like this:

```js
plainUser.aud = this.configService.get("JWT_TENANT")
```

When verifying the token, you would then introduce a check which confirms that the `aud` claim matches the current tenant.

```js
let { iat, exp, aud } = jwtPayload;
if (aud !== this.configService.get("JWT_TENANT")) {
  throw new UnauthorizedException();
}

// The rest of your validation code
```

**NOTE** I'm assuming you would run multiple application instances of your application with different configurations for each tenant, however if tenants are derived elsewhere then you should gather that information from the relevant data source instead.

Approaching it this way will ensure that you can identify the user and tenant that the user belongs to and prevent tokens from `tenant1` being used to access `tenant2`.